# How to decrypt RSA-OAEP message that has a label in web?

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, webcrypto-api

I'm struggling to find a way to decrypt a message that has a label.
Without providing the label, decryption will fail due to invalid padding. Webcrypto simply says "DOMException" without a stacktrace.

Go implementation of RSA does it in a couple of lines but doesn't appear to be so easy in web.

`decrypt_oaep.go`

```golang
package rsa

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base64"

    "crypto/rsa"
)

var fullEncryptedMessageWithLabel = "-----BEGIN MyCustomLabel MESSAGE-----\nTjBF2E+ORFCeFvOZAMgPNH7xt3fc2KZrbdG9xGBvGPKX+Yngec0YDpYvVMTtoDfV\nMLestU027YOLzhvhbK+LJ4MXw8y3g2nzr1ZBCemFpoO4pQIbn3rzj0SPMjjKCY7p\nL+vj+IyWrUicSEL2OaX7RVk5yfj3P624jbhYCnJl5gOqIJqfLlYMmzgBd5JdNxYk\nhtoJ11bJazi+vvyoPe7E8gO4sKjz1sLxMhaSw2SuapwSnYrTdmu9I9JHnck4+o1R\nlno9GfuxNaPBpNChsLSIYiokRrK0DTRkQtRYhvVKhRQu3CFXmT62dNuXIKDpmrUg\nUdhn/p07aSBCg/xLmbX45Q==\n-----END MyCustomLabel MESSAGE-----\n"
var cipherTextOAEP = "TjBF2E+ORFCeFvOZAMgPNH7xt3fc2KZrbdG9xGBvGPKX+Yngec0YDpYvVMTtoDfV\nMLestU027YOLzhvhbK+LJ4MXw8y3g2nzr1ZBCemFpoO4pQIbn3rzj0SPMjjKCY7p\nL+vj+IyWrUicSEL2OaX7RVk5yfj3P624jbhYCnJl5gOqIJqfLlYMmzgBd5JdNxYk\nhtoJ11bJazi+vvyoPe7E8gO4sKjz1sLxMhaSw2SuapwSnYrTdmu9I9JHnck4+o1R\nlno9GfuxNaPBpNChsLSIYiokRrK0DTRkQtRYhvVKhRQu3CFXmT62dNuXIKDpmrUg\nUdhn/p07aSBCg/xLmbX45Q==\n"

var privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\nCzXH4uwq5/nnDoZiuIwFUKHd76N1n4Yw0eAuhGKKZ9Xx8UWc59/JAz/j654=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

func (r *FastRSA) decryptOAEP(ciphertext, label, hashName, privateKey string) (string, error) {

    private, err := r.readPrivateKey(privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    ciphertextDecoded, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(ciphertext)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    output, err := rsa.DecryptOAEP(
        getHashInstance(hashName),
        rand.Reader,
        private,
        ciphertextDecoded,
        []byte(label),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return string(output), nil
}
```

usage example in `decrypt_oaep_test.go`

```golang
package rsa

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestFastRSA_DecryptOAEP(t *testing.T) {

    instance := NewFastRSA()
    output, err := decryptOAEP(cipherTextOAEP, "MyCustomLabel", "sha256", privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    t.Log("output:", output)
}
```

In webcrypto, doesn't work

```js
   // HELPERS
   function stringToArrayBuffer(byteString) {
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = byteString.codePointAt(i);
      }
      return byteArray;
    }
    function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64Text) {
      base64Text = base64Text
        .replace(/\n/g, "")
        .replace(/\r/g, "")
        .replace(/\t/g, "")
        .replace(/\s/g, "");
      const text = atob(base64Text);
      const stringLength = text.length;
      const resultView = new Uint8Array(stringLength);
      for (let i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
        resultView[i] = text.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      return resultView.buffer;
    }


   // LOGIC
   const key = await crypto.subtle.generateKey(
      {
        name: "RSA-OAEP",
        modulusLength: 2048,
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
        hash: "SHA-256",
      },
      true,
      ["encrypt", "decrypt"],
    );
    if (key.privateKey) {

      // This fails due to unknown exception without a stacktrace

      const decrypted = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
        { name: "RSA-OAEP", label: stringToArrayBuffer("MyCustomLabel") },
        key.privateKey,
        base64ToArrayBuffer(cipherTextOAEP),
      );
      console.log("decrypted", decrypted);
    }
```

Does anyone know how to achieve `decryptOAEP(cipherTextOAEP, "MyCustomLabel", "sha256", privateKey)` with webcrypto or equivalent? I'm lost currently.

Comment: When I run the Go code, I get an _undefined: FastRSA_.

Comment: Where in the WebCrypto code is the key from the Go code imported? Also, the definitions of `stringToArrayBuffer()` and `base64ToArrayBuffer()` are missing.

Comment: @Topaco In go, the logic comes from native crypto/rsa package, `rsa.DecryptOAEP`

Comment: @Topaco
Go is basically the same implementation from [this link here](https://github.com/jerson/rsa-mobile/blob/master/rsa/decrypt_oaep.go) ([and example](https://github.com/jerson/rsa-mobile/blob/master/rsa/decrypt_oaep_test.go)), only simplified for Stackoverflow.   

I added stringToArrayBuffer, base64ToArrayBuffer implementations to question as well.

Comment: The data is not consistent and therefore cannot be decrypted, not even with the Go code. Post consistent data and preferably also an executable Go code.

Comment: Thanks, you save my month. I spent a month to find this problem in webcrypto. I'm working with golang and javascript with RSA OAEP.